# Mandatory ORIENTDB_HOME and ORIENTDB_DIR

Tags: configuration, environment-variables, orientdb

I am begining to work with ORIENTDB and I have the following question.

Is it mandatory to set both environment variables? I was hoping to work with the studio without them, just setting the XML with my own environment variables.

Is there anyway to use custom variables programatically in my Java program?

Regards.

Comment: Hi Daniel, which version of orientdb are you using? Maybe the doc can help you https://orientdb.com/docs/last/Unix-Service.html

Comment: Hello ldacrema, I am using version 2.2.33 and it is an embbeded database in my java program, it works fine except that I need to set the mentioned environment variables else the studio won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally understood what is missing.

When the "OServerPluginManager" is at startup, it uses the ORIENTDB_HOME setted + "plugins" to check the directory and register the plugins.

But between setting the plugin directory using the environment variable and registering the plugins, there is a overriding of properties checking the Server Property "plugin.directory".

So adding the property at server level with the directory where the plugins are will fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to set environment variables to work with OrientDB unless you're planning to run it from outside of its `/bin` directory, such as a service.

[OrientDB Docs | Windows Service](https://orientdb.com/docs/last/Windows-Service.html)

[OrientDB Docs | Unix Service](https://orientdb.com/docs/last/Unix-Service.html)

Comment: And if it is embedded? Because the studio seems not to be running